# 3D mesh segmentation simple algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry

I am developing the algorithm reported in this article:

[Lest square conformal mapping](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Levy02.pdf)

Here is presented an algorithm to flat a 3d mesh on the parametric space, but i don't understand the segmentation step.

Does anyone know an alternative segmentation approach simpler than the algorithm presented in that article?

In other word, do you know a simple and efficient mesh segmentation algorithm?

The requirements are:

- charts boundaries should be positioned in such a way that most of the discontinuities between the charts will be located in zones where they will not cause texture artifacts,
- boundary curves corresponding to high curvature zones of the model.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: ftp://www1.idc.ac.il/Faculty/arik/ShamirPapers/SegmentShamir.pdf  The actual implementation details are not in the scope of this site. Maybe you could start from: https://www.slideshare.net/PirouzNourian/point-cloud-segmentation-for-3d-reconstruction and (http://hhoppe.com/poissonrecon.pdf and https://github.com/addam/mesh-reconstruction/blob/master/pcl.cpp) and https://people.cs.umass.edu/~kalo/papers/LabelMeshes/LabelMeshes.pdf On the other hand if you want to use curvature the work with normals is inevitable.